# getting the count of the table as Zero in codeigniter php

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i am having a table lab_master i need to get the total count of the tables i have written a query but getting the result as Zero as output.

Controller:

```
public function index() {
    $dateFrom = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 days'));
    $dateTo = date('Y-m-d');        
    $dataArr = array('from_date' => $dateFrom,'to_date'=>$dateTo);
    $countAllLabs = $this->dashboard->countAllLabs();
    $data['count_all_labs'] = $countAllLabs;
    $this->load->view('dashboard', $data);
}
```

Model:

```
public function countAllLabs($week = 'week', $date = '') {
    $TotalRecord = 0;
    $this->db->select('count(id) as TotalRecord');
    $this->db->from('lab_master lab');
    // $this->db->where('cancel_status', '');
    if (!empty($week)) {
        $dateFrom = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-6 days'));
        $dateTo = date('Y-m-d');
        $this->db->where("lab.created_date BETWEEN '" . $dateFrom . "' AND '" . $dateTo . "'");
    }
    if (!empty($date)) {
        $this->db->where("DATE_FORMAT('created_date,'%Y-%m-%d')", $date);
    }
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $result = $query->row();
        $TotalRecord = $result->TotalRecord;
    }
    return $TotalRecord;
}
```

View:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 userslist">            
                    <div class="user">
                        <i class="fa fa-user-o"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="userlist">
                        <ul class="lists">
                            <li class="list1">Labs: <?php echo $count_all_labs; ?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging the countAllLabs method?

Comment: Do what @Vigrant said - debug the model. My guess is that one or both of your "where" constructs isn't doing what you expect.